# Background repeated job

Tags: iphone, multithreading, xcode, background, nstimer

I have a question about multithreading in xcode. I have searched for numerous web sites but still cannot get my app to work. I want to do a repeated job every 5sec even the Home button is pressed i.e. continue to time in background. The following is my code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(test) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
 }
```

In test.m,

```
 -(void)test {
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(sayYeah) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
  [pool release];
}
```

in sayYeah.m,

```
-(void)sayYeah {
    NSLog(@"yeah");
}
```

What I expect is "yeah" will continue to pop up every 5sec even the home button is pressed. But it didnt, can anyone have an idea how the multithread should be implemented? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unless your app fall is the category VOIP, audio playback or location update.

And you can't use timers.

Comment: Because it's made by apple and they do not have bound by the AppStore rules.

Comment: o...sorry but I have one more question. From your answer, do you mean I can stop an audio, which is playing in background, in background?

Comment: No, you can make an app that plays audio in the background. Some apps play a sound to keep them running in background. but as soon as an other app start playing audio your app will be suspended.