# How to continue the timer after turning off the application

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I'm currently working on the app where I need to continue the timer after turning off the application. I think I need use NSDate and method intervalSince, but I don't know how to do it.
Language - Swift. Sorry if my English is bad :)
Thanks!

Comment: just save the date and check the interval next time the user opens the app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9841155/4475605

Comment: Adrian B, its an obj-c example and also there no such page on apple's website